# Email not sent when web-application-type set to none in spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot

I have a cron job which performs some operations and sends emails on exceptions. I am running into an issue where emails were not sent when I have the

```
spring.main.web-application-type=NONE
```

set in my application.properties file but I am able to receive emails when this is removed.

I need the above property to kick off the app each day by cron. If I remove this property app will run fine first time and throws below error on later executions

```
Address already in use
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol-9090]]
```

I had to kill the PID to reprocess it manually

Whats the issue here? How do I receive emails by retaining above property in my application properties file.

Below is my application.properties file

```
app.environment=DEV
server.port=9090
spring.main.web-application-type=NONE

spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxx;databaseName=xxx
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.validation-query=select 1
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true

smtpHost=test.com
username=emailagent@test.com
password=user
smtpPort=25
error.email.to=myemail@test.com
error.email.from=admin@test.com
```

My gradle file

```
 plugins {
   id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.6.RELEASE'
   id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'jdepend'

sourceCompatibility = 1.11

bootJar {
   baseName = 'my-cron-app'
}

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
} 

dependencies {
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')

compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat', module: 'tomcat-jdbc'
}

compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5')

compile('org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0')
compile group: 'net.sf.jt400', name: 'jt400-jdk8', version: '9.5'
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.4')
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
runtime('com.microsoft:sqljdbc4:4.0')

testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit'
}
```

I am using logback.xml file to configure this email properties placed out side the jar file

The crontab startup.sh file I use

```
echo "Starting the app now"
source ~/.bashrc
cd /dev/my-cron-app/
nohup /opt/jdk-11.0.2/bin/java -Xmx768m -Xms256m -Dlogging.config=/dev/my-cron-app/logback.xml -jar 
/dev/my-cron-app/my-cron-app.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev &> logs/console.log&
```

May I know what am I missing here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to figure it out what was the problem. It sounds odd I had to put few seconds time delay soon after my email trigger code before the app shuts down for the day. I am thinking this email delivery process was somehow aborted by the immediate closure of the Entity manager and connection pool. It sounds strange to me but it worked

Answer (score 2):

Without the `spring.main.web-application-type=NONE` setting, Spring Boot will configure your application to run in an embedded Tomcat container. The app will start and Tomcat will listen for web requests indefinitely, until you stop the app. Trying to run the app a second time will result in a port conflict on port 9090, as you've seen.

With the `spring.main.web-application-type=NONE` setting, Spring Boot won't start the embedded Tomcat container, and the app is likely to exit immediately after it finishes starting up.

Your question is missing the important detail of how you are writing the main application logic that performs the processing and sends the e-mails, and how you expect that logic to be invoked. If you want the app to start up, do the processing, and exit when done, then you should look at implementing the processing using an `ApplicationRunner` or `CommandLineRunner` as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner).

Comment: is there a way to do this in reverse? Having `spring.main.web-application-type=NONE` but keep in running?

Comment: You need something to create a thread and keep that thread alive to prevent the application from exiting normally. Tomcat or any embedded web server will do this. Scheduling tasks will also (see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks). Spring Boot 3.2 will add a new `spring.main.keep-alive` property to allow you to configure an app to stay alive without any other features (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/37736).